# Why do Lada's fuel gauge looks like this?

Tags: fuel-system, car

This is picture from Lada's fuel gauge.

[image]

Any idea why it says 4/4 when the tank is full?

The logical sequence is: 0, 1/2, 1.

Comment: Because math dictates 4/4 = 1 and "1" equates to full?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you're right! 0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4 and then 4/4. By the way, even some old Mercedes cars have this as well.

Comment: I've seen a lot of different European cars with this same thing.

Answer (score 1):

4 quarters = 1 complete ie the full tank is divided into 4 equal parts.

But, most if not all fuel gauges are inaccurate - so it may show 3/4 but the amount in the tank may not be that at all or the distance possible...